# DataTable to Array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have a `DataTable` which consists of dynamic rows:

```
no   |   cid   | wait  |  prio
--------------------------------
1    |   1234  |  0:57 |    0
2    |   54785 |  0:44 |    0
3    |   74125 |  0:22 |    0
```

I want to create an array of arrays from this, having information of each row in an individual array.

Comment: The implementation of a `DataTable` is an array of arrays. The `Rows` property is the outer array and then each row has an `ItemArray` which is an `object[]` of values for that row.

Comment: Can you code your statement as I am very new in .Net.

Comment: Is this a Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It doesn't matter once it's in a data table where the data came from...

Comment: @Servy, the OP is effectively asking me to show him how to get the data from the database into the `DataTable` yes?

Comment: Your data table already has everything you want, creating separate arrays is just adding pain to your process.  I would suggest researching "accessing data from DataTables".

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud No, he's asking how to get the data *out* of a `DataTable` and into an array of arrays.

Comment: @Servy, gotcha, it's a very confusing question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I fail to see what's confusing.  It opens with, "I have a DataTable" not "I need to get a DataTable".

Comment: @Servy, as the comments progressed it *appeared to me* that the OP was interchanging the term `DataTable`.

Comment: @Evanlewis: I think you are right, I followed your advise.

Comment: Glad I could help, I did post a small code example of what I was talking about.  If it helps please mark it as such =)  Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I applaud other users for answering your direct question regarding an array of array.  I think you are making this more difficult than you need to.

```
    yourDataTable.Rows[rowIndex]["no"]
```

is already an array containing all the values in your "no" column.

```
    yourDataTable.Rows[rowIndex]["cid"]
```

is already an array containing all the values in your "cid" column.

etc... etc..

You can access the data by either looping through the rows, or calling one directly in place of `rowIndex` as shown above, and assigning the value in the column to some other variable.

If you *really* want to get arrays of arrays (which you already have), then disregard this and refer to the other answers.

Comment: Though I'm only assuming here, the OP is likely sending this data to another assembly (i.e. unmanaged C or something like that) and it only supports an array.

Comment: I considered that, but also felt that perhaps he does not know how to access the data directly, so thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud While that's a possibility, [that doesn't appear to be the case here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942380/datatable-to-array-of-arrays/16942689?noredirect=1#comment24462215_16942380)

Comment: Hey now, don't start arguing in comments on my answer please ;)

Answer (score 8):

Although you don't need this

```
var arr = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably work as intended:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
foreach (object row in DataGridView.Rows)
    {
    List<object> newList = new List<object>();
    list.Add(newList);
    foreach (object columns in row)
    {
        newList.Add(columns.DataBoundItem);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

There is no need to create array for data tables.